# Each in SASS function

Tags: sass

I want to use sass (ideally indented syntax) to apply the same transition to several different properties. To do so, I wanted to use the @each directive. I've searched for examples, but documentation on functions in sass is pretty spotty.

here's what I have:

```
@function default-trans($trans...)
  $out: ()
  @each $tran in $trans
    append($out, "#{$tran} 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55)")
  @return $out

#sidebar
  transition: default-trans(background-color width)
```

expected result:

```
#sidebar {
  transition: background-color 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55), width 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55)
}
```

I am getting an error saying: 
Functions can only contain variable declarations and control directives.

I doubt that the problem is really my append function, but am guessing that I have some kind of syntax error that I can't sufficiently debug.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sending a list then you have to use comma separated value

```
transition: default-trans(background-color, width)
```

When you are appending the result you need to assign it to the output again.

change from

```
append($out, "#{$tran} 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55)")
```

to

```
$out: append($out, #{$tran} 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55), comma)
```

code block

```
@function default-trans($trans...)
  $out: ()
  @each $tran in $trans
    $out: append($out, #{$tran} 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55), comma)
  @return $out

#sidebar
  transition: default-trans(background-color, width)
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you for taking the time to go through that so exhaustively. It's really appreciated.